# How to get multiple dynamic row value into the database using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

```
public void create(account_detail c, int jobcard_id)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data source =(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Wattabyte Inc\Documents\CarInfo.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;

    con.Open();
    string additionalText = string.Empty;
    bool needComma = false;

    foreach (var details in c.Data)
    {
        if (needComma)
        {
            additionalText += ", ";
        }
        else
        {
            needComma = true;
            additionalText += "('" + jobcard_id + "','" + details.completed_by + "','" + details.reporting_time + "','" + details.cost_activity + "','" + details.spared_part_used + "')";
        }

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into child_detail values " + additionalText + ";";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

I am using this code but it only taking single value but I want to save multiple values into the database. How can I achieve this?

Comment: When you say multiple values, do you mean Many `jobcard_id`'s  or `account_detail`?

Comment: For the love of god use entity framework.

Comment: many jobcard id and please i have to use ado.net

Comment: if any body know how to do that please help its urgent

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: can u help me for writing the code please its urgent

Answer (score 1):

If you need multiple `jobcard_id` then do this.
**Note** this is making it fit in your code, I suggest you do some refactoring and figure out a better way to do this because it's just plain ugly.

```
public void create(account_detail c, List<int> jobcard_ids)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data source =(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Wattabyte Inc\Documents\CarInfo.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
           string additionalText = string.Empty;
             bool needComma = false;

             foreach (var details in c.Data)
              {
                 if (needComma)
                 {
                      additionalText += ", ";
                 }

                      else
                 {

                     needComma = true;
                  foreach(var jobcard_id in jobcard_ids)
                  {
                     additionalText += "('" + jobcard_id + "','" + details.completed_by + "','" + details.reporting_time + "','" + details.cost_activity + "','" + details.spared_part_used + "')";
                     if (jobcard_id != jobcard_ids.Last())
                     {
                         // We will need to comma separate the query string unless it's the last item
                         additionalText+= ","; 
                     }
                  }
                }
                 cmd.CommandText = "insert into child_detail values " + additionalText + ";";
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

              }
```

Comment: sir i tired this code but still getting the single value please help me

Comment: When we reach the `cmd.CommandText` what is the value of `additionalText`? Does it look to be correctly formatted `TSQL` with all your values in there?

Comment: it takes only first value and after second value it comes out of the loop